beanstalk - project files not being copied
I'm trying to publish a PHP app with this Docker: https://gallery.ecr.aws/dwchiang/nginx-php-fpm
So according to its docs I'm using this Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/dwchiang/nginx-php-fpm:7.4.28-fpm-bullseye-nginx-1.24.0

COPY . /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

With this Dockerfile in my project root dir I'm deploying it to Beanstalk:
eb create my-env

It creates the environment fine but via browser it shows Welcome to Nginx page.
So I entered eb ssh and saw that /var/www/html folder was not created with my project files as the Dockerfile command.
How is this possible?
Am I doing something wrong?
